# .Net MySQL Driver is not handling \" appropriately

Tags: mysql, .net

I have a query:

```
UPDATE tableA SET content = '[{\"Id\":7,\"FParam\":{\"html\":\"\\\"<p>\\\\n\\\\ttest</p>\\\\n\\\"\"}}]',time = 1379516448 WHERE id = 1107;
```

When run with phpMyAdmin, content column has the following **correct** value:

```
[{"Id":7,"FParam":{"html":"\"<p>\\n\\ttesting publishing</p>\\n\""}}]
```

When I run the query using the .NET MySQL Framework using the following simple code:

```
using (var connection = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString)) {
    await connection.OpenAsync();

    string updateCommandSQL = "UPDATE tableA SET content = '[{\"Id\":7,\"FParam\":{\"html\":\"\\\"<p>\\\\n\\\\ttest</p>\\\\n\\\"\"}}]',time = 1379516448 WHERE id = 1107"

    using (var updateCommand = new MySqlCommand(updateCommandSQL, connection))
    {
        return await updateCommand.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
    }
}
```

I get the following result in the db:

```
[{"Id":7,"FParam":{"html":""<p>\n\ttest for group</p>\n""}}]
```

As you can see the SQL is the same in both sources. For some reason MySQL Framework is not running the same update statement.

Am I missing something? Is there a formatting option or settings when opening the connection or anything like that? Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is `encoded` coming from?

Comment: Yeesh, sounds like a good use for parameterized queries..

Comment: That "simple" code is horribly broken. **Do not use string concatenation to add data to an sql command!** It's practically begging to get hacked.

Comment: I have edited the question. My question focuses around the result of the query more so than how we get there. I have taken your suggestions and will convert my code to use parameterized queries at a later date.

Comment: You ask for suggestions and yet you're not whiling to take them. If you were using @MikeChristensen 's suggestion you would not have such a issue.

Comment: Didn't realize it was a potential fix. I will test it out and revert back.

Comment: @user1137939 Well the difference is that you don't have to go out escaping things you can pass the variable the way you receive it and it should insert it just fine and do what it needs to.

Comment: Parameterized query did the trick. Thanks for all of your help.

Comment: @MikeChristensen How can I mark your comment as the solution? If you create your comment as an answer, I can mark this as resolved.

Comment: @user1137939 - Sure, done!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can spend a lot of time trying to escape your string correctly, but I'd *strongly* suggest parameterizing your query instead.  This will solve your issue, as well as prevent possible SQL injection attacks from occurring.

First, create your SQL statement:

```
string updateCommandSQL = "UPDATE tableA SET content = @content, time = @time WHERE id = @id";
```

Next, add the three parameters to your `SqlCommand`:

```
updateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@content", newContent);
updateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@time", 1379516448);
updateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", 1107);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Mike! This solved my issue. I'll be changing the rest of my application to use parameterized queries as well.